# Invitaion to facebook friends is not working

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying this code to invite facebook friends.But it did not work for me.Invitaion dialog is opened properly but no friend got invitaion.

can anyone please try this code at their end ,it will not take more then 2 minutes and let me know is this working at their side.

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
FB.init({
appId:'APP_ID',
cookie:true,
status:true,
xfbml:true
});

function FacebookInviteFriends()
{
FB.ui({
method: 'apprequests',
message: 'Your Message diaolog'
});
}
</script>


//HTML Code
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<a href='#' onclick="FacebookInviteFriends();"> 
Facebook Invite Friends Link
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nitika..
Now a days facebook doesn't show invitation on its notification,
Your invitation will be seen at 
[Appcenter/ Request](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/requests)

one more things about callback from FB.ui

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

this callback will work for you to save request id for future use.

Comment: i checked it also.can you please try this code at your end.it will not take more then 2 minutes..i read somwhee that still your app is in sanbox mode still no one can see invitaion?

Comment: hi, its working fine for me. Just for info, your app is live or not.

Comment: i am trying this code for local host...how to make app live..please let me know??

Comment: You go to your fb app setting and disabled sandbox mode and may be Facebook ask to add category of your app. thats it :)